# Que estoy haciendo mal con FETCH

Tags: nodejs

Que estoy haciendo mal.

Porque trato de solicitar datos al servidor por medio de FETC pero se queda en pendiente.

Esto es lo que he intentado de dos maneras y es lo mismo..:

```
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/presupuestos/readAllfetch'
       

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())  // convertir a json
        .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error)) // Capturar errores    
        .then(json => console.log(json))    //imprimir los datos en la consola


        /* let extraePresEnca = async () => {
            let respuesta = await fetch(url)
            let json = await respuesta.json()
            return json
        }
        extraePresEnca().then(presEnca => console.log(presEnca)) */
```

Esto tengo en el ROUTER.. :

```
router.route('/readAllfetch')
    .get(presupuestosController.readAll1)
```

Esto tengo en el CONTROLLER..:

```
    readAll1: async(req, res, next) =>{
        try {
            const [presupuestos, _] = await Presupuestos.readAll()
            //console.log(presupuestos)
            return presupuestos
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es que no estas retornando los valores correctamente a la peticion sino solo retornas un valor, para eso se ocupa el atributo `res` que aparece en los parametros del metodo get

intenta con esto

```javascript
readAll1: async(req, res, next) =>{
        try {
            const [presupuestos, _] = await Presupuestos.readAll()
            //console.log(presupuestos)

            // return presupuestos -> reemplaza esto por lo siguiente
            return res.json(presupuestos) // en caso que 'presupuesto sea un objeto json o arreglo json'
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

en la documentación de expressjs puede conocer mas las funcionalidades de esos parametros: [Writing middleware for use in Express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: Es correcto..! modifique y recibo los datos.

Comment: favor de votar la respuesta a favor para que a mas les sirva el dato

Comment: He votado... espero sea correcto... (soy nuevo aquí)..